# Guava TypeToken and generic classes

Tags: java, generics, guava

I'm using Guava [TypeToken](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) class in my project, but I'm getting an unexpected result.

I have `MyGenericClass<T>`:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> implements MyInterface {

    private TypeToken<T> recordType;

    public MyGenericClass(String name) {
        this.recordType = new TypeToken<T>(getClass()) {};

        // ...
    }

    // ...

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected Class<T> getRecordType() {
        return (Class<T>) recordType.getRawType();
    }
}
```

So if I instantiate an object via `new MyGenericClass<String>()` and then invoke `getRecordType()` I expect to get `java.lang.String`, instead I'm getting `java.lang.Object`.

But, if I extend generic class:

```
public class MyStringImpl extends  MyGenericClass<String> {
    // ...
}
```

and instantiate this new class: `new MyStringImpl()` then I get the correct result.

Why is this happening? Is this the expected behaviour of `TypeToken`?

Comment: *"Is this the expected behaviour of TypeToken?"* Yes, it is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To make this work you need the same anonymous subclass trick when you instantiate `MyGenericClass`:

```
new MyGenericClass<String>() {}
```

If you do that then you will get `String` returned by `getRecordType`.  The reason why this is necessary is explained in the [JavaDocs for that `TypeToken` constructor](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#TypeToken(java.lang.Class)).

> Clients create an empty anonymous subclass. Doing so embeds the type parameter in the anonymous class's type hierarchy so we can reconstitute it at runtime despite erasure.

Answer (score 17):

To add some boring details to Ian's answer: It would be nice if `TypeToken` worked the way you expected, but this is impossible. When you declare

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> implements MyInterface {...}
```

the JVM sees something like

```
public class MyGenericClass<Object> implements MyInterface {...}
```

due to erasure.

But when you declare

```
public class MyStringImpl extends MyGenericClass<String> {...}
```

then in the definition of `MyStringImpl` the generics used are recorded and can be obtained via [`Class#getGenericSuperclass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass()). That's (a part of) the magic behind `TypeToken`.